# Unable to deploy List of Metadata fields to Layout by apex

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, list-metadata

When i deploy Layout with 1 field everything works fine whereas when i deploy fields as list, not even single field is showing in the Layout. Below is the code i am using for field creation, then assign profile and at last add it to the Layout:

```
public class DynamicDatapoints {
    public static void dynamicCreation(list<String> lstOfDataPointsToInsert){

        //create instance and session id for metadata service
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

        //create instance for metadata create custom field class

        List<MetadataService.CustomField> lstAllCustoField = new List<MetadataService.CustomField>();
        for(integer i=0; i<lstOfDataPointsToInsert.size(); i++){
             MetadataService.CustomField customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
            customField.fullName = lstOfDataPointsToInsert[i];
            customField.label = lstOfDataPointsToInsert[i];
            customField.type_x = 'Text';
            customField.length = 42;
            lstAllCustoField.add(customField);
            List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results =
            service.createMetadata(new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { customField });
            system.debug('results>>'+results);
        }          

        //create instance for metadata profile class
        MetadataService.Profile admin = new MetadataService.Profile();
        for(String str: lstOfDataPointsToInsert){
            admin.fullName = 'Admin';
            admin.custom = false;
            MetadataService.ProfileFieldLevelSecurity fieldSec = new MetadataService.ProfileFieldLevelSecurity();
            fieldSec.field=str;
            fieldSec.editable=true;
            admin.fieldPermissions  = new MetadataService.ProfileFieldLevelSecurity[] {fieldSec} ;
            List<MetadataService.SaveResult> result = service.updateMetadata( new MetadataService.Metadata[] { admin });
            system.debug('Success FLS' + result);
        }     

        //Adding created fields to a Layout
         Metadata.CustomMetadata customMetadata =  new Metadata.CustomMetadata();
        List<Metadata.Metadata> layoutList  = Metadata.Operations.retrieve(Metadata.MetadataType.Layout, new List<String> {'Account-Account Layout'});
        if(layoutList != null && !layoutList.isEmpty()){
            Metadata.Layout layoutMetadata = (Metadata.Layout) layoutList.get(0);
            list<Metadata.Layout> listlayoutMetadata = new list<Metadata.Layout>();

            Metadata.LayoutSection sec = new Metadata.LayoutSection();
            sec.customLabel = true;
            sec.detailHeading = true;
            sec.editHeading = true;
            sec.label = 'Keyword fields';
            sec.style = metadata.LayoutSectionStyle.OneColumn;
            system.debug('inside Section');
            Metadata.LayoutColumn LayoutColumnsItems = new Metadata.LayoutColumn();
            list<Metadata.LayoutColumn> listLayoutColumnsItems = new list<Metadata.LayoutColumn>();

            Metadata.LayoutItem layoutField =new Metadata.LayoutItem();  
       //     list<Metadata.LayoutItem> listlayoutField =new list<Metadata.LayoutItem>();
            Metadata.DeployContainer dc;
            list<Metadata.DeployContainer> listdc =new list<Metadata.DeployContainer>();  
            String field;

            for(String st: lstOfDataPointsToInsert){

                field = st.removeStart('Account.'); 
                //layoutField = new Metadata.LayoutItem();              
                layoutField.field = field;
                layoutField.behavior = metadata.UiBehavior.Edit;
                system.debug('inside layout section' + field);
                //LayoutColumnsItems = new Metadata.LayoutColumn();
                LayoutColumnsItems.layoutItems.add(layoutField);

                system.debug('check Items' + LayoutColumnsItems);
                sec.layoutColumns.add(LayoutColumnsItems);
                layoutMetadata.layoutSections.add(sec);
                //listLayoutColumnsItems.add(LayoutColumnsItems);


                listlayoutMetadata.add(layoutMetadata);
            }

            system.debug('check sectionss -->' + listlayoutMetadata);
            for(Metadata.Layout objLaoutMeta : listlayoutMetadata){
                dc = new Metadata.DeployContainer();
                dc.addMetadata(objLaoutMeta);
                system.debug('dc>>'+dc);
                Id jobid2 = Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment(dc,null); 
                system.debug('Metadata Deployment'+jobid2);
            }
```